# How to spread a list in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

In Javascript I would use a spread operator:

[image]

Now I have the same problem with Flutter:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyHeader(),
        _buildListOfWidgetForBody(), // <- how to spread this <Widget>[] ????
        MyCustomFooter(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: You may want to read https://medium.com/flutter-community/quick-tip-sync-a-taste-of-the-future-9be4cd6993f4

Comment: Keyword for people with Ruby-background: splat operator [*[1, 2], 3]

Comment: @RémiRousselet firstly, thank you for Riverpod, I am just learning it but it seems very capable.  However, with the spread operator, I saw this other use case here:https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/d9a8b4a7ef358cacbe3938411835086b7aa3b468/examples/todos/lib/main.dart#L113  What is that doing?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can now do spreading from **Dart 2.3**

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4];
var b = [6,7,8,9];
var c = [...a,5,...b];

print(c);  // prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 14):

There is an issue to add this to future version of dart https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47

but for now you can use `sync*`  and `yield*`

```
Iterable<Widget> _buildChildren sync* {
  yield MyHeader();
  yield* _buildListOfWidgetForBody();
  yield MyCustomFooter();
}
```

**EDIT**: As of Dart 2.3 you can now do:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyHeader(),
        ..._buildListOfWidgetForBody(),
        MyCustomFooter(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

## Update - 20th April 2019

You can now use the spread operator since **Dart 2.3** was released.

```
List<int> a = [0,1,2,3,4];
List<int> b = [6,7,8,9];
List<int> c = [...a,5,...b];
```

Comment: I saw another use case here where the `...[` is before the list bracket:  https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/d9a8b4a7ef358cacbe3938411835086b7aa3b468/examples/todos/lib/main.dart#L113

Answer (score 0):

**FireStore** use another field in model

```
authInstance
    .collection('fav_product')
    .add(
{
...product.toMap(),
'field':'value',
}
);
```