# How can I spread a List in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to unpack a list in dart? I want to do something similar to this python snippet:

```dart
return proc(*args)
```

Comment: I'm not going to VTC because I'm not sure, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709124/how-to-spread-a-list-in-dart) answers your question.

Answer (score 8):

Dart does not support unpacking a List into function arguments.

However, you can unpack a List into another List by typing three dots `...` before the list name.

```dart
List<int> oneTwo = [1, 2];
List<int> oneTwoThree = [...oneTwo, 3];

print(oneTwoThree); // [1, 2, 3]
```

More info here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator