# What does "..." or ".." mean in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

While looking at some code written in flutter, I keep seeing "..." used in different situations, but do not really understand how and why it is used.
Here is an example :

```
 CircleAvatar(
        radius: size / 2,
        child: DragTarget<Animal>(
          builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) => Stack(
            children: [
              ...animals
                  .map((animal) => DraggableWidget(animal: animal))
                  .toList(),
              IgnorePointer(child: Center(child: buildText(text))),
            ],
          ),
          onWillAccept: (data) => true,
          onAccept: (data)
```

Can someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Dart developer, so take everything I'm about to say with a grain of salt, but from what I read, the `...`, called [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) behaves in a similar fashion to the Javascript one. It allows you to split collections, set, etc, into its  items.

It's especially useful to insert a collection into another, like so

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list]; 

// list2 contains 0, 1, 2, 3
```

As for the `..`, the [cascade operator](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-), the answer was quite well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447736/list-use-of-double-dot-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got the "cascade operator" fine. For the Spread operator, I don't really understand how to use it, in which concrete situation I need to use it... But I will try to research on it as I now know what it is called.

Comment: @SylvainJack Here are some links explaining the spread operator with examples 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822127/9414608  2. https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples 3.https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-and-bug-free-code-with-dart-operators-2e81211cecfe

Comment: @SylvainJack the spread operator is the same as `list2 = [0];   list2.insertAll(1, list)`. It's just a different way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone !! In the example that I copied in my question, why do we use it there in the "CHILDREN" section of the Stack ?

Comment: You are officially a Dart developer now!

Comment: @SylvainJack It's just a preferred way than writing this: `children: animals.map((animal) => DraggableWidget(animal: animal)).toList().insert(animals.length, IgnorePointer(child: Center(child: buildText(text)))),`

Comment: Ah ok I see !! Thanks !! I have another question :) While reading the link you sent me, I saw in the MEDIA.COM article an example that I don't really understand. Here is the code : "final addressBook = (AdressBookBuilder()..name = 'jenny'..email='jenny@ex.com').build();      Why do we use the "...builder() and /Build()" What is it for ?

Comment: @Peter Haddad :) Thanks :) but just a beginner :) but wanting to learn a lot !! :)

Comment: @SylvainJack The `AddressBookBuilder()` and `build()` are just methods that the author use. The cascade operator in the simplest form, is just used so you don't have to write the same object multiple times. For example with cascade operator: `var paint = Paint();
paint.color = Colors.black;
paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
paint.strokeWidth = 5.0;` and without `var paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.black
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..strokeWidth = 5.0;` (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation)

Comment: Thanks ! That's crystal clear ! And the fact that he ends this allocation with .build() ? do you see what it can be ?

Comment: @SylvainJack its just a custom method, I think they are showcasing the builder design pattern with the cascade operator, this is the pattern in java though: (https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

Comment: I saw in your profile that you were very knowledgeable in FIREBASE FIRESTORE etc... I use FIREBASE & FIRESTORE in my app. Everything works fine, however, when building the app, I get a lot of NOTES in red saying "Firebase uses deprecated APIs" etc.... RECOMPILE with Xlint etc.... Is this a bug with the package ?

Answer (score 1):

***(..) Cascade Operator***

The two dots (..) in the expression SomeClass()..someMethos(locale) are the cascade operator in Dart. It allows you to perform multiple method calls on the same object in a single line of code.

Why use Cascade Operator?

Readability: When chaining multiple method calls on the same object, the cascade operator improves readability by avoiding repetition of the object reference.

Conciseness: It allows you to write a more concise expression compared to separate lines for object creation and method calls.

Example:

```
final languageProvider = LanguageProvider()..setLocale(locale);

// Alternative without Cascade Operator:

final languageProvider = LanguageProvider();
languageProvider.setLocale(locale);
```

***(...) Spread operators***

Spread operators evaluate an expression that yields a collection, unpacks the resulting values, and inserts them into another collection.

1. Copying a List:

```
// Create a list of numbers
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3];

// Create a new list with the spread operator
List<int> newNumbers = [...numbers, 4, 5];

print(numbers); // Output: [1, 2, 3]
print(newNumbers); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

2. Combining Lists:

```
// List of fruits
List<String> fruits1 = ['apple', 'banana'];

// List of vegetables
List<String> vegetables = ['carrot', 'potato'];

// Combine them using spread operator
List<String> allProduce = [...fruits1, ...vegetables];

print(allProduce); // Output: [apple, banana, carrot, potato]
```

3. Modifying a List (with caution):

```
// List of numbers
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3];

// Attempt to modify the original list (not recommended)
numbers = [...numbers, 4]; // This modifies the original list

print(numbers); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

4. Using Spread Operator with Maps:

```
/ Define a user profile
Map<String, String> profile = {
  'name': 'John Doe',
  'age': '30',
};

// Create a new map with additional information
Map<String, String> fullProfile = {
  ...profile,
  'city': 'New York',
};

print(profile); // Output: {name: John Doe, age: 30}
print(fullProfile); // Output: {name: John Doe, age: 30, city: New York}
```

5. Spread Operator with Null-aware Safety:

```
// User object with a potentially null address
class User {
  String name;
  String? address; // Address might be null

  User(this.name, this.address);
}

// Create a User object
User user = User('Alice', null);  

// Spread operator with null-awareness
Map<String, String> userData = {
  'name': user.name,
  'address': user.address?, // Only include address if it's not null
};

print(userData); // Output: {'name': Alice} (address is omitted)
```