# Ternary operator inside loop generated 'ListView'

Tags: flutter

Im a flutter beginner, actually to the whole Software development domain,

I have a list generated with a loop, i want to add `Divider()` after '*Three*', and '*Six*', preferably using ternary operator, either, or if-else,

You may try the code, by [visiting](https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> items = <String>[
  "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
];

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
              ListTile(title: Text(items[i])),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add `Divider` after three and six, But using ternary operator, you are replacing the `ListTile` widget with `Divider`.

`val? true:false`, means here only one will be return. What you need to just check the index and add divider only after `three` and `six`, `if` statement is perfect for this as @Josteve mentioned on his answer. While in `children` can only be widget instead of list, he is using `Column` to merge `Divider` and `ListTile`, you can use [`spread operator`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) instead.

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) ...[
      ListTile(title: Text(items[i])),
      if (i == 2 || i == 5) const Divider()
    ]
  ],
),
```

You can check more about [spread-operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) and [use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54709124/10157127).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) ...[
    ListTile(title: Text(items[i])),
    if (i == 2 || i == 5) const Divider()
]
```