# how to have a extra dropdown menu item in the dropdown button - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fetching the customer name record from firebase and displaying it inside the dropdown button as a menu items which I did it succesfully but along with that, I'm trying to add a one extra dropdown menu item called 'add a new customer', so basically I'm trying to figure out that how to display one more menu item along with firebase fetched items

here is my code

```
DropdownButton<CustomerModel>(
                                hint: Text('SELECT CUSTOMER', style: GoogleFonts.oswald()),
                                value: customerModel,
                                items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((e){
                                  CustomerModel customerModel = CustomerModel(customerId: e['customerId'], customerDocumentId: e.id, customerName: e['name'], customerMobile: e['mobile'], customerCity: e['city'], customerAddress: e['address'], createdOn: e['createdOn'].toDate());
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(value: customerModel, child: Text(customerModel.customerName.toString().toUpperCase(), style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.black54)));
                                }).toList(), // displaying all customer names from firebase, I want to have one more extra menu item called 'ADD A NEW CUSTOMER'
                                onChanged: (value){
                                  setState(() {
                                    customerModel = value;
                                    customerId = value!.customerId;
                                    customerDocumentId = value.customerDocumentId;
                                    customerName = value.customerName;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```dart
items: [
  ...snapshot.data!.docs.map((e){......).toList(),
  DropdownMenuItem(..yourNewItem..),
],
```

Comment: Thanks bhai! Worked like a charm! By the way, what is the purpose of having three dots at the beginning? What it does?

Comment: This is known as spread operator, It is something like unpacks the values and put it. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54709124/10157127)

Comment: I see! Thank you for letting me know! One last question, by default, I wanted to show the hint text which is 'select customer' which is no longer showing up (after implementing the solution)

Comment: you can call `hint:Text("Select customer")`  on `DropdownButton`, and make `customerModel` nullable. when `customerModel` is null, it will show hint